# I need to know how to save a python variable value to a text file and load it

Tags: python

Well the title says most of it. Its the part at the end, where I try to dump the variable using json but it doesn't work, probably because it's a variable. So I need to know a way I can save/load this variables data.

My code:

```
import json
import time



datastore = json.load(open("file.json"))
menuon = 1






def add_user():
    userdata = input("How many users do you wish to input?")
    print("\n")

    if (userdata == 0):
        print("Thank you, have a nice day!")

    else:
        loop = int(userdata)
        whileloop = loop+loop


        while loop < whileloop:
            appendnumber = json.load(open("fileappend.json"))
            loop = loop + 1
            datastore.append([])
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Name: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Email: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter DOB: "))
            appendnumber = appendnumber + 1
            json.dump(appendnumber, open("fileappend.json", "w"))


def print_resource(array):
    for entry in datastore:
        print("Name:  "+entry[0])
        print("Email:  "+entry[1])
        print("DOB:  "+entry[2])
        print("\n")



def search_function(value):
  for eachperson in datastore:
      if value in eachperson:
          print_resource(eachperson)






while menuon == 1:        
    print("Hello There. What would you like to do?")
    print("")
    print("Option 1: Add Users")
    print("Option 2: Search Users")
    print("Option 3: Replace Users")
    print("Option 4: End the program")
    menuChoice = input()


    if menuChoice == '1':
        add_user()

    if menuChoice == '2':
        searchflag = input("Do you wish to search the user data? y/n")
        if(searchflag == 'y'):
            criteria = input("Enter Search Term: ")
            search_function(criteria)

    if menuChoice == '3':
        break


    if menuChoice == '4':
        print("Ending in 3...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("1")
        json.dump(datastore, open("file.json", "w"))
        menuon=0
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? Is it putting the wrong information in the file? Is there a stack trace? If so could you post the stack trace?

Comment: NameError: name 'appendnumber' is not defined. That pretty much explains it, it doesnt regonise it as a value.

Comment: Or is it because its a integer that it doesnt like it?

Comment: @Flux Actually, it doesn't completely explain it.  What line is that on?  You have `appendnumber` multiple times in the code.  It helps if you tell us which one is the offending one.

Comment: @Tim Wilder Ok, updated code, everything I need saved/imported works but my search function now just seems to print all of the data in the array not just the seperate subarrays

Comment: @Flux I'm glad that works. Stack Overflow is best organized to ask a series of questions like that separately, since it's hard to convert answers to many different questions in one post, and the results are less useful to future readers. Try to ask a question with a narrow focus, and maybe post multiple questions as you iterate. Read this! http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Noted. Will make a stack overflow question later to avoid spam

Answer (score 0):

Can we get more information about what is going wrong? A contained example using some of the same code as you are works.

```
import json

with open("file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(["TEST"], f)

datastore = json.load(open("file.json"))
print(datastore)

datastore.append("TEST2")
json.dump(datastore, open("file.json", "w"))

datastore = json.load(open("file.json"))
print(datastore)
```

Edit: You need to assign to appendnumber in the same scope as it is used to write.

Try running this example snippet and see what happens:

```
def test():
    appendnumber = "HUZZZAAAAHHH"

test()
print(appendnumber)
```

To fix the problem, assign to appendnumber in the scope of your module by assigning in the while loop. Something like this is the general idea of what you want to do:

```
def add_user():
    appendnumber = 5
    return appendnumber

x = 0
while x < 10:
    appendnumber = add_user()
    print(appendnumber)
    x += 1
```

You asked how to pull a value from a function. To do that you would add a return to the end of the add_user function, then in your loop assign to the returned value from the function. This wouldn't necessarily fix all problems in the script but it is an invaluable tool for a programmer.

```
def add_user():
    userdata = input("How many users do you wish to input?")
    print("\n")

    if (userdata == 0):
        print("Thank you, have a nice day!")

    else:
        loop = int(userdata)
        whileloop = loop+loop
        appendnumber=-1

        while loop < whileloop:
            loop = loop + 1
            appendnumber = appendnumber + 1
            datastore.append([])
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Name: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter Email: "))
            datastore[appendnumber].append(input("Enter DOB: "))
    return appendnumber
```

In the loop at the bottom of your code:

```
if menuChoice == '1':
    appendnumber = add_user()
```

I think reading about functions and scope would give you the ability to tackle similar problems going forward, so that might be a good use of time!

There's a few other minor bugs floating around, but for the sake of moving forward, I would focus on learning why you can't access values defined only in a function's scope, and how to assign to the return value of a function.

Comment: Im trying to save the variable "appendnumber" to a text file and reimport it when the program reloads.

Comment: `appendnumber` isn't previously defined in your posted code. I think that's a likely culprit?

Comment: I set its value on line 24?

Comment: The code that writes it to the file can't "see" the variable as it is assigned in the add_user function. That function gets its own space where variables are named and have values given to them, but outside of it, references to appendnumber will fail. Check this out: http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: Ok so how I do I pull the value out of the function I made?

Comment: @Flux `return` it from the function

Comment: @SethMMorton
I havn't returned variables from functions before, would you like to elaborate?:)

Comment: You want to return it from the function, and assign to it in the while loop.

Comment: @Tim Wilder I have it set up so it saves append number, but during the save process it runs the function add_user()

Comment: @Tim Wilder edited my OP to my current code, basically, when I end the program and it hits the save function, it runs add_user(0

Comment: @Flux You want to do the assignment in your if `menuChoice == '1'` part where you call `add_user`, not as a call at the end. I'll make that change to the OP with some edit markers.

Comment: @Flux  There's a number of other puzzles you'll probably need to work through, but it's going to be much easier to do what you want if you read about scope and assignment. Once you get the variable assignment working, I might consider looking at that loop+loop component, and as a separate thing, think about what happens if a user hits 4 before they've appended anything.

Comment: @Flux Your menu choice integer 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
jsonString = json.dumps({ 'check': 'test', 1: 2, 2: [1,2,3] })
open('test.json', 'w').write(jsonString)
jsonToParse = open('test.json').read()
jsonObject = json.loads(jsonToParse)
print(json.dumps(jsonObject))
```